# Regular Expression failing in Response Assertion and Regular Expression Extractor Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

The response data in my test has this line:

```
<head><title>
    My Title
</title><meta charset
```

I checked this regex in the inbuilt regex tester in Jmeter and it found the title.

```
(?m)(?is)<title>\n\tMy Title\n</title>
```

However, when I use it as a response assertion, the assertion always fails.

I have tried all settings in "Apply to" section. "Text Response" is selected for "Response Field to Test". I selected "Contains" for "Pattern Matching Rules".

I have a very similar issue with a regular expression extractor as well - the selected expression passes in the tester, but fails with regular expression extractor.

I believe it may have something to do with the multi-line nature of the response.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try use:

`(?<=<title>\s*)(\S.+\S)(?=\s*</title>)` for find any title

`(?<=<title>\s*)(My Title)(?=\s*</title>)` for find 'My title'

Comment: I get this error: `Assertion failure message: Bad test configuration org.apache.oro.text.MalformedCachePatternException: Invalid expression: (?<=<title>\s*)(\S.+\S)(?=\s*</title>)
Sequence (?<...) not recognized`

Comment: try without (?<=) and (?=)              `<title>\s*(My Title)\s*</title>`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
Regular Expression: <title>(.+?)</title>
Template: $1$
Match: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [xpath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) instead.

Use expression like `//title/text()` along with [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) - to extract title value, - and expression like `//title[text()='My Title']` along with [XPath Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion).

In both the cases you have to ensure that that Use Tidy (tolerant parser) option is CHECKED - since you are parsing HTML (not XML!..) response.

Comment: xpath assertion is more resource consuming in comparison to response assertion

Comment: ...as well as using regular expressions to parse xhtml may appear less generic, reliable and handy way to do things and create sustained and maintainable tests: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/993246. Anyway it depends only on the situation and your choice.